# Pairwise seqence alignment in Biopython

Tags: alignment, biopython

How to do pairwise sequence alignment in Biopython? Can I get sample code for this?

Answer (score 2):

Follow the tutorials at the [BioPython website](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#htoc74).  They show example of how to setup alignments using ClustalW, MUSCLE, and EMBOSS alignment algorithms.

To get any further help you will need to try something out and share your attempt and the challenges you are facing.